# Squared euclidean distance in Racket using a hash-set

Tags: racket

I am trying to write a function that computes the [squared Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance#Squared_Euclidean_distance). I originally stored the data inside lists of the form:

```
'(1 8 0 0 0 1 0 5 0 1)
'(1 0 2 0 0 0 0 5 0 0)
```

And basically what I try to obtain is the sum of:

```
'(0 64 4 0 0 1 0 0 0 1)
```

Using lists this isn't hard to achieve, like with the code from bellow:

```
(define (f a b)
  (apply + (map (λ(x y) (sqr (- x y))) a b)))
```

However the data that I'm working with got quite many zeros in it, so instead I tried to replace lists with hash-sets, like so:

```
'#hash((0 . 1) (1 . 8) (5 . 1) (7 . 5) (9 . 1))
'#hash((0 . 1) (2 . 1) (7 . 5))
```

Here when I try to rewrite the `f` function but with hash-sets I get stuck, because I don't know how to iterate over both of them directly. What I wrote so far doesn't count the elements that are in the second hash-set but not in the first one.

```
(define (f a b)
  (for/fold ([sum 0])
            ([(k v) (in-hash a)])
    (+ sum (sqr (- (hash-ref b k 0) v)))))
```

Is there a way to achieve this in a fast way (preferably using a single for)? Or perhaps is there a better way to work with sparsed lists (that contain many zeros)?

Comment: Notice that there's a bug in your test data, in the second hash you should have a `(2 . 2)` not a `(2 . 1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to get a list of all indices which occur in *either* of the sparse vectors, and then to map over that list of indices to calculate the squared distances:

```racket
(define (sparse-sum-of-squares u v)
  (let ((indices (remove-duplicates (append (hash-keys u) (hash-keys v)))))
    (apply + (map (lambda (i) (let ((x (hash-ref u i 0))
                                    (y (hash-ref v i 0)))
                                (sqr (- x y))))
                  indices))))
```

You should probably do some actual testing on your data to see if performance is an issue before you start complicating the data representation. After fixing the sparse vectors in the posted example so that they match, here are the results:

```
sparse-vector.rkt> (f '(1 8 0 0 0 1 0 5 0 1)
                      '(1 0 2 0 0 0 0 5 0 0))
70
sparse-vector.rkt> (sparse-sum-of-squares '#hash((0 . 1) (1 . 8) (5 . 1) (7 . 5) (9 . 1))
                                          '#hash((0 . 1) (2 . 2) (7 . 5)))
70
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, we need to handle missing values in *both* hashes. Iterating only over indexes with actual values, we can do something like this:

```
(define (squared-euclidean-distance a b)
  (for/fold ([sum 0])
            ([idx (set-union (hash-keys a) (hash-keys b))])
    (+ sum (sqr (- (hash-ref a idx 0)
                   (hash-ref b idx 0))))))
```

We simply return `0` if an index is missing. It works as expected:

```
(squared-euclidean-distance
 '#hash((0 . 1) (1 . 8) (5 . 1) (7 . 5) (9 . 1))
 '#hash((0 . 1) (2 . 2) (7 . 5)))
=> 70
```